# SMTP Server Times Out for 1 of 2 ISPs

Tags: email, smtp

For months I've been using a 5g sprint card for my laptop to check email. I have gmail, and three other accounts all configured in Thunderbird. Recently, I got AT&T internet service at my house and I discovered that I cannot *send* email when connected to my home service. I can *receive* just fine, but I can't send. If I plugin my 5g card, I can sent/receive with no problems.

At home I'm connected wirelessly through a router. What could be causing this interruption? I even tried pinging my smtp server only to see it timeout when connected via AT&T. If more details are needed, I'll be happy to share.

**Correction**: Sending through Gmail's smtp works. What types of things should I look for to diagnose the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most residential ISPs restrict outgoing connections on port 25: Only connections to the ISP's SMTP server are allowed, any other outgoing connections on port 25 are blocked.

If your third-party e-mail is using an SMTP server on port 25, see if you can use other ports instead. (This [GoDaddy support page](http://help.godaddy.com/article/4878) suggests you can access your SMTP server on ports 25, 80, or 3535 without SSL, or on port 465 with SSL.)

Answer (score 0):

Some ISPs limit access to their outgoing SMTP servers to IP addresses on their network.  Google doesn't. If you are attempting to send to Sprint's SMTP server from AT&T that may be your problem.

Comment: I'm sending to a third-party SMTP, hosted with GoDaddy.